# Откуда взялось "сбрендить"

Tags: этимология

Недавно сын звонит мне из магазина и спрашивает: "Не купить ли конфеты с бренди?" И сам же смеется: "Ты, наверное, думаешь, что я сбрендил". А мне подумалось: а чем черт не шутит, нет ли в этой шутке правды? Не связано ли слово "сбрендить" с употреблением этого напитка?

Comment: Вспоминается такая история: http://zajcev-ushastyj.livejournal.com/395179.html

Comment: Вот уж не ожидала этот вопрос получит баллы, да еще так много! Спасибо сыну!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре Шведовой обнаружила такое пояснение:  **Сбрендить** - из *с-брендить*, ср. диал. *брендить*, экспрессивный вариант к *бердить*, производн. от *бёрдо* ‘часть ткацкого станка’; развитие знач.: ‘качаться как бёрдо’ > ‘пятиться назад’ > ‘отставать, не надеяться на собственные силы’ > ‘трусить’.

Comment: А причем тут трусость? По-моему, сбрендить - значит сойти с ума.

Comment: СБРЕНДИТЬ, Разг.-сниж. 1. Устар. Струсить, испугаться.
 Сбрендил, не полез драться.
 2. Устар. (что). Соврать или сказать глупость, чепуху. Сбрендил, и в толк не взять.
 3. Сойти с ума. Парень совсем сбрендил. Сбрендил с ума. 
 4. Устар. Упасть духом, отчаяться. Больной совсем сбрендил.
(Большой толковый словарь)
В сегодняшнем широком словоупотреблении из 4 значений осталось одно - 'сойти с ума'. Остальные, в том числе и 'струсить', устарели.

Answer (score -1):

От слова "бред" -- "сбредить" -- сказать бред,  потом переиначилось.