# Происхождение слова "сбрендить"

Tags: этимология

Сбрендить - еще один эпитет для понятия "сойти с ума", только более насмешливый и просторечный. Но интересно было бы узнать, откуда это слово вообще взялось? Честно говоря, не могу представить, от какого корня оно образовано. Разве что речь о слове "бренди", и "сбрендить" - находиться в состоянии, аналогичном пьяному?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В прошлый раз не исследовалась связь звучания слова (или истории его употребления) с его современным значением, ясно только, что образовалось оно с другим значением. "Бред" или 'brain' почудилось в его звуке первоприменителям? В прошлом году на Comedy Central в этом смысле своеобразно пошутили над Дэном Брауном, автором усложнённых квазинаучными гипотезами детективов "Код да Винчи" и "Инферно". За спиной литератора происходила перестановка букв его имени и фамилии: 'Dan Brown' сначала превратили в комплиментарное 'Brand Now', а потом в 'Bra(i)n Down' (почти "вынос мозга").

Answer (score 2):

Бренди (англ. brandy, сокращение для brandywine, от нидерл. brandewijn — жжёное вино, от branden — сжигать; wijn — вино) — алкогольный напиток[1], общий термин для обозначения продуктов дистилляции виноградного вина, фруктовой или ягодной браги (обычно крепостью 40—60 % об). Если явно не указано иное, то бренди изготавливается из виноградного вина. Обычно употребляется после еды.Происхождение бренди неясно, но крепко связано с развитием перегонного винокурения. Концентрированные алкогольные напитки известны с античных времён Греции, Рима и Китая[2]. Бренди такой, каким он известен сегодня, впервые появился в XII веке и стал популярен в XIV веке.

от мозгов не катит, зато катит в мозги.  Торговая марка берендеев.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь повтор вопроса

[Откуда взялось "сбрендить"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7419/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)